# discord.js - Bot wont add role: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot to moderate my server. I wanted to add a command that gives the author any role by using the command `!role [role name]`.

I used this:

```js
const member = message.author
const rle = message.content.split(/ +/).slice(1).join(' ');
const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === `${rle}`);

try {
  member.roles.add(role1);
} catch (e) {
  message.author.send(${e});
}
```

It (given I spell the role correctly) returns the following error:

`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"`

Does anyone know how I would fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `author` property does not have a `roles` property. This is a common mistake. `message.author` returns a `User` class, while `message.member` returns a `GuildMember` class.

All you have to do is change `message.author` to `message.member` and it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const member = message.author
const rle = message.content.split(/ +/).slice(1).join(' ');
const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === `${rle}`);
                
        
 try 
  {
   message.guild.member(member).roles.add(role1);
  }


 catch (e) 
  {
   message.author.send(${e}); 
  }
```